# i cant post user to db, get method give me data from db, but post or delete dosen`t working

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

[Suagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlnLo.png)
[executing result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr7Tf.png)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
    public class UserController{
    private final UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    @PostMapping
    public void createUser(@RequestBody User user){
    userService.createUser(user);
}
}
```

this is my controller and post method for user entity

Answer (score 0):

because post method not return User, it's `void` method

```
@PostMapping
public User createUser(@RequestBody User user){
   return userService.createUser(user);
}
```

Comment: 403 forbidden again